# When choosing $2$ pets randomly among $12$ dogs and $15$ cats, what is the probability that they are both cats?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

When choosing $2$ pets randomly among $12$ dogs and $15$ cats, what is the probability that they are both cats?

Comment: What did you try? What's the answer for only one pet? How could you make use of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability))?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing the first pet, the probability to take a cat is $\frac{15}{15+12}$. After that, there are $14$ cats remaining and still $12$ dogs. The probability to pick a cat again is thus $\frac{14}{14+12}$.

Finally, the probability of both events happing is simply the multiplication of the two, that is

$$\frac{15}{15+12}\cdot \frac{14}{14+12}=\frac{15}{27}\cdot \frac{14}{26}=\frac{35}{117}.$$

Comment: Did you happen to read the comments, following the posting?  If the posting does not follow the MathSE protocol, is the posting supposed to receive an answer?